# Kafka topics are deleted after restart

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, azure-aks, persistent-volumes

I have a kubernetes cluster with one zookeeper pod and three kafka broker pods.

Deployment descriptor for zk is:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ZOOKEEPER_ID
          value: "1"
        - name: ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_1
          value: zookeeper
        - name: ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT
          value: "2181"
        - name: ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME
          value: "2000"
        name: zookeeper
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.0.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2181
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/zookeeper/
          name: zookeeper-data
      nodeSelector:
        noderole: kafka1
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: zookeeper-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: zookeeper-volume-claims
```

And for kafka brokers are like the following (one for each broker with the correspondant broker names, listeners and persistent volume claims):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: kafka1
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE
          value: "true"
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
          value: "PLAINTEXT://<ip>:9092"
        - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
          value: "PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092"
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          value: <ip>:2181
        - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
          value: "1"
        name: kafka1
        image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.0.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/kafka
          name: kafka1-data
      nodeSelector:
        noderole: kafka2
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: kafka1-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: kafka1-volume-claim
```

The cluster is up and running and I'm able to create topics and publish and consume messages.

The file log.1 exists in /var/lib/zookeeper/log/version-2

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 67108880 Jan 18 11:34 log.1
```

And if I run into one of the brokers:

```
kubectl exec -it kafka3-97454b745-wddpv bash
```

I can see the two partitions of the topic:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 21 10:34 test1-1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 21 10:35 test1-0
```

The issue comes when I restart the virtual machines when zookeeper ant brokers are allocated. One for zk, and one for each broker (three vm's that conform my Kubernetes cluster)

After restart, in everyone of the brokers, there are no topics:

```
root@kafka3-97454b745-wddpv:/var/lib/kafka/data# ls -lrt
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan 21 10:56 cleaner-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   54 Jan 21 10:56 meta.properties
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 21 10:56 __confluent.support.metrics-0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 21 10:56 _schemas-0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   49 Jan 21 11:10 recovery-point-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4 Jan 21 11:10 log-start-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   49 Jan 21 11:11 replication-offset-checkpoint
```

And in zookeeper:

```
root@zookeeper-84bb68d45b-cklwm:/var/lib/zookeeper/log/version-2# ls -lrt
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 67108880 Jan 21 10:56 log.1
```

And if I list the topics, they are gone.

Kubernetes cluster is running on Azure.

I assume that there is not a problem related to the persistent volumes, since when I create manually a file in there, after restarting, the file is still there.
I think that is something related to my kafka config.
As you can see I'm using confluent docker images for that.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It was simply a wrong configuration on mount path. Paths have to point to the data and transactional log folders, instead of parent folders.

Comment: And what is the proper mount path should be?